# Github allowing one's changes to replace from feature branch

Tags: git, github

As we are using gitHub as a licence for our project. we are getting code issues and because of this we got fired from our clients.

Let me explain........

We are creating a feature branch from master branch , lets called it "X" & "Y". Now "X" completed work before "Y" and merged code into master. Now "Y" comes and says I want to merge because they also completed the development but "Y" don't have changes which "X" did so when "Y" merges code into master , github allowing "Y" to wipe out "X" changes without giving any warning or conflict.

Is that a github feature or bug ?

Comment: This sounds very serious, but honestly if your planned solution is posting to Stack Overflow, you might need to restructure your team and bring in some more senior people who are familiar with your technologies.

Comment: Can you share how are you creating feature branches and how are you merging them back to the master

Comment: As to your observations, yes, Git can do an auto merge and "wipe" some stuff out.  But, that _usually_ doesn't happen if you have good branching strategy.  Not good branching strategy would have multiple engineers all working on the same file, even worse, in the same areas of the file.  Then, Git might get smart and wipe out some stuff during a merge.

Comment: I agree @TimBiegeleisen . But then what is the good branching strategy and why git is not showing any warning during merge.

Comment: Just re-read my comment.  _Avoid_ having multiple team members all doing stuff to the same files/same areas of same file.  If you do this, then you'll minimize merge conflicts.  Bad planning is the root cause of your problems here.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya we are creating feature branch from master. so after one's change, other feature branches are behind so git should observe that. And we are creating pull request from feature branch to merge it in master.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Then why git says that parallel development is their feature. There are high chances that multiple people can work on same file if you aware of agile methodology.

Comment: Yes...but not two very separate branches, where each version steps on the toes of the other version.  You have bad branching strategy at work here.  Branch often, merge often, don't overlap.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Just to add something, In agile each person works on their own item which has unique id and using that id we are creating a feature branch to have a track of each item. if any bug comes then its easy to rollback respective code from that track.

Comment: Did you do push Y with `--force`  to master :) ?

Comment: @GhasemNaddaf. Nope. we are doing simple merge.

Comment: Whoever has down voted this question should able to explain the good strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this seems highly unlikely to happen unless **there were conflicts on Github** *and* **whoever worked on Y rebased/merged master and wiped out all of X's changes**.

The teams I work with also follow work on features the way you have described. We have best practices in place to ensure no one wipes out another team's code. Some of them are

- Tests ensuring no one is introducing regression bugs
- Pull requests don't get merged unless they are up to date with the master branch. We follow a rebase strategy, but you can also use a merge strategy
- If the projects are closely related, they go to an epic branch first where they are thoroughly tested against requirements using automated tools as well as A/B testing before they are merged into master.

These pretty much ensure that there are fewer merge conflicts and if they do occur, it is easier to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I see two different problems here :

### Merging deleted work

This is definitely not a problem from Github. I saw this kind of problem around with people (including me) who weren't yet trained to using Git properly.

I strongly advise you and all your team member to read the [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) thouroughly, at least the first chapters. It might give you some headache at first as it did to me, but I really saw the benefit right away.

Also keep in mind that merging works done by two different people *on the same file* is very time consuming and error-prone. So try to organize your project and your team so that it happens as rarely as possible.

### Have a workflow that corresponds to your team and situation

This question is very broad. You can read [this](https://www.toptal.com/software/trunk-based-development-git-flow) as a starting point.